# Using gelf4net to send amqp to graylog

Tags: log4net, graylog

Anyone know if it's possible to send GELF AMQP messages straight into Graylog with [gelf4net](https://github.com/jjchiw/gelf4net)?

I can see old posts about using the old graylog2 radios to subscribe to rabbitmq or similar brokers.  But then found [this post](https://www.graylog.org/announcing-graylog-v1-0-ga/) which says it's now built into graylog v1.

The gelf4net setup looks simple enough - but how do I setup the GELF AMQP input in Graylog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uff 3 years later...

I don't search for gelf4net questions in StackOverflow :/ since there are no many questions I usually answers them in github..

This is the `log4net.config`

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="GelfAmqpAppender" type="Gelf4Net.Appender.GelfAmqpAppender, Gelf4Net.AmqpAppender">
        <remoteAddress value="127.0.0.1" />
        <remotePort value="5672" />
        <username value="guest" />
        <password value="guest" />
        <virtualHost value="/" />
        <exchange value="log-messages" />
        <key value="#" />
        <layout type="Gelf4Net.Layout.GelfLayout, Gelf4Net.AmqpAppender">
            <param name="AdditionalFields" value="app:GelfAmqpAppender,version:1.0,Level:%level" />
            <param name="Facility" value="RandomPhrases" />
            <param name="IncludeLocationInformation" value="true" />
            <!-- Sets the full_message and short_message to the specified pattern-->
            <!--<param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%t] %c{1} - %m" />-->
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="AsyncGelfAmqpAppender" type="Gelf4Net.Appender.AsyncGelfAmqpAppender, Gelf4Net.AmqpAppender">
        <remoteAddress value="127.0.0.1" />
        <remotePort value="5672" />
        <username value="guest" />
        <password value="guest" />
        <virtualHost value="/" />
        <exchange value="log-messages" />
        <key value="#" />
        <layout type="Gelf4Net.Layout.GelfLayout, Gelf4Net.AmqpAppender">
            <param name="AdditionalFields" value="app:AsyncGelfAmqpAppender,version:1.0,Level:%level" />
            <param name="Facility" value="RandomPhrases" />
            <param name="IncludeLocationInformation" value="true" />
            <!-- Sets the full_message and short_message to the specified pattern-->
            <!--<param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%t] %c{1} - %m" />-->
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="GelfAmqpAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="AsyncGelfAmqpAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

the property `<exchange value="log-messages" />` you should create the `Exchange` and a `Queue` named `log-messages` in the RabbitMQ Console

[image]
[image]

And here is the Input configuration in Graylog

[image]
[image]

This configuration is my dev environment, you should go deeper in RabbitMQ and Graylog for an optimal configuration